# CRM Report Miscalculating columns

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have created a custom column, in a CRM report, and the column sometimes does not calculate the answer correctly.

See Attached image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3D4J.jpg

The left column is: `=CDbl(Sum(Fields!ask_totalduration.Value/60)).ToString("N1", Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.RdlHelper.ReportCultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(Parameters))`

The Middle column is: `=Fields!ask_response.Value`

The right column is: `=iif(Fields!ask_response.Value>Fields!ask_totalduration.Value, "Time Met", "Time not Met")`

As seen in the picture, something is not working properly, but I am unable to figure it out.

Thanks Joe

Comment: I have now got it to format in 2 decimal places. I am still however unable to get it to show the correct output! See attached screenshot: http://imgur.com/IijkmL3   (Sorry I don't have enough points to post images)

Comment: This still appears to be an issue. I unable to find how to solve it. http://imgur.com/zvt6LYu     (If the left column is lower than the right it should display a message saying Time Met, otherwise display the message Time not met.

Comment: I have now located the problem to be the decimal numbers. It is not looking at the decimal numbers while calculating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it might be a type coercion issue.

Try changing your formula to this:
`=IIf(CDbl(Fields!ask_response.Value) > CDbl(Fields!ask_totalduration.Value), "Time Met", "Time not Met")`

This will ensure no implicit conversions are being performed.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep it simple you can use below formula since you have only 2 decimal points.

```
iif(Fields!ask_response.Value *100 >Fields!ask_totalduration.Value *100, "Time Met", "Time not Met")
```